# How to read url from .txt file and use in html src?

Tags: javascript, html, url, text

How can I read url from a txt file and use in html? I have a video source url in .txt file. How can I use this url in the html file? Sometimes I want to edit the video source in the .txt file.

In the /videosrc.txt:

```
http://www.videoexaple.com/videos/video.mp4
```

In /index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<video id="video">

<source id="videosource" src=" -url from /video.txt- " type='video/mp4'>

</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this on a web server or your harddisk? Does the URL of the HTML file start with https:// or file:////

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
fetch('file.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => { document.getElementById("videosource ").src =text;})
```

Comment: Assuming they are on a web server

Comment: @nondee mark as answered if the answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you give this a read:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp
See the first example and you can see the output of the file.

This shows you how to access information within a file. Then it is just a matter of putting the data at the correct place.

Comment: You are assuming a) they are on a web server and b) they have PHP and c) they can code PHP

Comment: As it was not defined, yes, assumptions were made. But no, I do not think they can code PHP as this question came up here. However, it is a nudge in a working direction.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to have a file with the extension .js - for example video.js in the same folder as the html file

It looks like this:

```
const videoURL = "https://www.videoexaple.com/videos/video.mp4";
```

then in your HTML have

```
<script src="video.js"></script>
<script>
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
    document.getElementById("videosource").src = videoURL;
  })
</script>
```